# "Nothing indicated" error when trying to append all objects from a blend file with Python

Tags: python, scripting, append

I try to use `bpy.ops.wm.append()` to import everything from Objects section of a source *.blend file into my master *.blend file. Here’s my code:

```
blendfile = "Z:\Source.blend"
section   = "\\Object\\"
bpy.ops.wm.append(directory = blendfile + section)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: 'D:\Source.blend\Object\': nothing indicated
```

It seems that Blender wants me to specify an object, but I’d like to append everything from the Objects section.

Comment: I ran blender with --debug-all and the command generated when I selected all in the append object folder included each object separately in a files array. It looks like you will have to get a list of all the objects and then request them all.

Comment: Thanks! That actually helped!